# How to group a list of dicts based on part of the key from the dict

Tags: python, list

I'm having troubles with grouping my list

so let's say I have this:

```
data = [
{'records-0': '1'}, {'records-0-item1': '2'}, {'records-0-item2': '3'},{'records-0-item3': '4'},
{'records-1': '1'}, {'records-1-item1': '2'}, {'records-1-item2': '3'},
]
```

What I'm trying to have is my list sorted based on the index that is in my key (if that makes any sense).

So my expected outpout would be kinda like this.

```
sortedData = [
{0: [{'records-0': '1'}, {'records-0-item1': '2'}, {'records-0-item2': '3'},{'records-0-item3': '4'},]},
{1: [{'records-1': '1'}, {'records-1-item1': '2'}, {'records-1-item2': '3'},]
]
```

I've tried looking up for grouping lists, but that all is based on one specific key. like this
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/group-list-of-dictionary-data-by-particular-key-in-python/

Any ideas?

**EDIT**: The data in the list is based on user input, so there could also be a:

```
{'records-2': '1'}, {'records-3': '1'}, {'records-4': '1'}, etc
```

Comment: Maybe `sortedData = {0: [{'records-0': ''}, {'records-0-item1': ''}, {'records-0-item2': ''},{'records-0-item3': ''}],
1: [{'records-1': ''}, {'records-1-item1': ''}, {'records-1-item2': ''}]}`?

Comment: Well, the data is actually dynamic, so I can't just hardcode it.

Comment: So in the resulting list, the values will be empty string? So the `{'records-0': '1'}` in the input would be `{'records-0': ''}` in the output? Or was it just typo?

Comment: Personally I would say your input data isn't stored in a proper format. You **don't** need dictionaries there, a list of dictionaries each having only one key-value pair? Might as well have a list of tuples / lists.

Comment: @NielGodfreyPonciano Yeah it's actually a type, my bad

Comment: I've refactor sortedData into only nested dictionnaries if you'd like to try this approach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use [default_dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

First, just define a helper method to get the key from the string:

```
def get_key_from(string):
    return int(string.split('-')[1])
```

Then

```
from collections import defaultdict

sortedData_res = defaultdict(list)
for h in data:
    k = next(iter(h))
    sortedData_res[get_key_from(k)].append({k: ''})
```

So you finally get this result:

```
sortedData_res

#defaultdict(list,
#            {0: [{'records-0': ''},
#              {'records-0-item1': ''},
#              {'records-0-item2': ''},
#              {'records-0-item3': ''}],
#             1: [{'records-1': ''},
#              {'records-1-item1': ''},
#              {'records-1-item2': ''}]})
```

---

Or adjust the code to get something different.

For example if you `.append(h)` instead you get:

```
#defaultdict(list,
#            {0: [{'records-0': '1'},
#              {'records-0-item1': '2'},
#              {'records-0-item2': '3'},
#              {'records-0-item3': '4'}],
#             1: [{'records-1': '1'},
#              {'records-1-item1': '2'},
#              {'records-1-item2': '3'}]})
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you reformat your sortedData and remove lists. You could gather your data only into dict.

*Edited* example: (should work as is)

```py
def sort_data(l_: list):
    d_ = dict()
    for d in l_:
        for k, v in d.items():
            i = re.split('-', k)[1]
            if not d_.get(int(i)):
                d_[int(i)] = dict()
                d_[int(i)][k] = v
                continue
            d_[int(i)][k] = v
    return d_
```

```py
>>> data = [
    {'records-0': '1'}, {'records-0-item1': '2'}, {'records-0-item2': '3'}, {'records-0-item3': '4'},
    {'records-1': '1'}, {'records-1-item1': '2'}, {'records-1-item2': '3'},
]
>>> print(sort_data(data))
{
    0: {
        'records-0': '1', 
        'records-0-item1': '2', 
        'records-0-item2': '3', 
        'records-0-item3': '4'
    }, 
    1: {
        'records-1': '1', 
        'records-1-item1': '2', 
        'records-1-item2': '3'
    }
}
```